# Call a custom function inside a bash command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin +1 -type f -name "240*.ts" 
| xargs -L 1 bash -c 'mv "${1}" "$(get_crtime${1} | awk '{print $5}').ts"' \;
```

The idea is to find files that are older than one minute matching a certain pattern (in my case, files that start with '240') and rename them from their original name (240-1458910816045.ts) to a desired format (15:00:16.ts).

Inside the script I am using get_crtime command which is a custom function included in /etc/bash.bashrc and has the following implementation:

```
get_crtime() {

    for target in "${@}"; do
        inode=$(stat -c '%i' "${target}")
        fs=$(df "${@}" | awk '{a=$1}END{print a}')
        crtime=$(sudo debugfs -R 'stat <'"${inode}"'>' "${fs}" 2>/dev/null |
        grep -oP 'crtime.*--\s*\K.*')
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "${target}" "${crtime}"
    done
}
```

When I call the function from the shell, like this:

```
get_crtime 240-1458910816045.ts | awk '{print $5}'
```

I get the desired output:

```
15:00:16
```

Which is a portion from the file creation date.

My problem is when I include the function call inside my initial script I get the following error:

```
}).ts": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
}).ts": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I think this is caused by incorrect invoking of awk, so I thought to remove it and leave just:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin +1 -type f -name "240*.ts" 
| xargs -L 1 bash -c 'mv "${1}" "$(get_crtime ${1}).ts"' \;
```

I get the following error, which is more suggestive:

```
;: get_crtime: command not found
```

**How can I call the custom function inside the bashrc inside the initial command without getting the last error?**

Thank you!

- The OS is Ubuntu
- The shell is bash

Comment: You can't. `xargs` is starting a separate bash process that doesn't know anything about your functions or local variables. I suggest you to stop using `xargs` and friends, and learn about shell scripting

Comment: You could do it as a for loop instead. Since you want to keep the find do it like `for file in $(find ...); do mv "$file" "$(get_crtime "$file")"; done`

Comment: @KurtStutsman **never** write a for loop that runs on the output of a command like that as it's prone to breakage given some file names. Use `cmd | while IFS= read -r file` or similar instead.

Comment: @EdMorton there is nothing wrong with writing it that way if you know the file names will be well formed as in his case. There are only a minor number of cases where that is not true. Also using a while loop forces your code into a subshell and introduces problems of its own.

Comment: That's like saying there is nothing wrong with leaving shell variables unquoted if you know their contents will be well formed. Just do it the robust way and you won't get any surprises and/or form bad habits. If executing a subshell as a consequence creates a problem, use process substitution or one of the other workarounds, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024, or reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use single quotes inside a single-quote delimited script. Look:

```
$ bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$(date | awk '{print $0}')"'
-bash})": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
-bash})": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

$ bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$(date | awk "{print \$0}")"'
Fri, Mar 25, 2016  8:59:31 AM
```

I'm not recommending you use double quotes around your awk script though - create a script to do the mv, etc. for you or figure out some other way to implement it that'll solve your function access problem too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the function:

```
export -f get_crtime
```

That will make it available to child `bash` processes (but not to other shells).

Also, as @EdMorton points out, you cannot use single quotes inside a single quoted-string, which was the problem with the invocation of `awk`. So you'll need to come up with a different way of quoting the interior argument to `awk`, or fix `get_crtime` to just return the string you want.

By the way, you might consider using `find`s `-exec` action instead of `xargs`. That would allow you to use a loop over a number of files, which would be a bit more efficient.

eg.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin +1 -type f -name "240*.ts" \
     -exec bash -c 'for f in "$@"; do
                      mv "$f" "$(get_crtime "$f" | awk {print\$5}).ts"
                    done' _ {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, used *modification time* of file, which can be get by `stat -c '%y'`. The `xargs -I` param creates possibility to place file name two times, first for `stat`, second for `mv`. Then using *Parameter Expansion* bash features to extract only *time* from human readable `stat` output:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mmin +1 -type f -name "240*.ts" | \
xargs -I_ bash -c 'MTIME=$(stat -c '%y' "_") && MTIME=${MTIME#* } && mv "_" ${MTIME%.*}.ts'
```